# Python webapp not running properly on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, websocket, socket.io

I tried to deploy [this application](https://github.com/shanealynn/async_flask) on Heroku. When i launch it locally on my laptop it runs properly, but after deploying it on Heroku to see the outcome i encountered some problems: i can see the whole frontend of the app online but the random numbers are not appearing dynamically on the webpage.

I don't know how to debug it, because on my Heroku console no errors are showing up, so i'm not getting any error at all. Any advice?

My procfile looks like this:

```
web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 orig:app
```

Edit 1:
I opened my Google Chrome console and found this:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fast-everglades-74376.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://fast-everglades-74376.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=2e9895ef6415455eac51294746b3edf6'. This endpoint should be available via WSS. Insecure access is deprecated.

socket.io.min.js:1 POST http://fast-everglades-74376.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1540729336006-41&sid=f550b39a0e1e4544b1eee0c3f1719871 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```

Also, on Firefox Console i'm getting another error about Mixed Active Content

Edit 2:
I changed the version of my Gunicorn module from 19.3 to 18.0 and after that i tried to run the page on http instead of https. On http it seems to run, the problem is that it won't run on https right now.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding deployment to *heroku*, you need to install `eventlet` for *socket-io apps* to run. Also, you need a `Procfile`. It basically tells *heroku* "apps" how to run. In my example [here](https://github.com/PinkFrojd/material_aukcije_online/blob/master/Procfile), just put that one line:

```
web: gunicorn -k eventlet python_file:flask_variable_name
```

In you example it would be I think

```
web: gunicorn -k eventlet application:app
```

Also, when deploying, be sure to add `Procfile` from *heroku* dashboard and set it to *"On"*.

Comment: Hey, i edited the question and added the procfile! Take a look to it!

Comment: Hi. On  github, there is no Procfile and what you wrote in Procfile, that "orig:app", you dont have orig.py. It should be application:app, beucase you are running your flask app from application.py file. Just to add, herkoku has automatic deployment when you push to github. Just link it.

Comment: So i edited my procfile and used the one you gave me but it's not working yet, same issue. Could it be with the flask_variable_name part?

Comment: How did you deploy your application to heroku ?

Comment: I created a requirements.txt file and the procfile, used git init and git add ., committed the app with git commit and then pushed everything. Here is the outcome: https://fast-everglades-74376.herokuapp.com/, as you can see the whole frontend part is there but i'm missing the numbers

Comment: Did you push your application again ? You need to push your local changes to github (I don't see them), and when you do that, go to heroku, go to deploy tab, and go to manual deploy. From there select branch, and when everything is finished, go to "overview" tab on heroku, and configure your dyno to use Procfile.

Comment: Yes, each time i edit something i commit my local changes and push everything again. About the Procfile, when i go to Overview i can see the procfile enabled near "web"

Comment: Can you link me your github repository where you push your changes ?

Comment: Of course, how can i do that? Sorry, i'm new to this. By the way i'm editing the question, take a look

Comment: We can't write more comments I think, but take a look at these photos and my repo that I linked in first answer.
https://ibb.co/d8rniA
https://ibb.co/gNHSiA
https://ibb.co/iegniA
Read description of images

Comment: Unfortunately i did not link any Github account to my Heroku account, i'll do it! By the way the whole code is on the repo i linked on the second line of my question. My procfile is exactly like yours but i placed "orig" instead of "application" because it's the name of the main file that i need to run. Take a look to my edits, i think the issue has to do with that

Comment: Try to load you application with http instead of https ??? http://fast-everglades-74376.herokuapp.com

Comment: With Http i'm getting socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1540733250966-15&sid=f7236b35f690435482f653ce5ed17f43:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (BAD REQUEST)

Comment: Edit: i changed the version of Gunicorn from 19.3 to 18.0 and on http it seems to work. I now need to figure out how to make it run on https too.

Comment: Please refrain from adding irrelevant fluff like "Oh hi. It's me again, with those answers to previous flask-socketio questions." Questions and answers should focus on pertinent information.